# SMS API URL Not Responding

Tags: php, curl, sms-gateway

**I am implementing a SMS Gateway API in Web Application. Using this following php code :**

```
<?php 
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'apiurl');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       $output = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch); 
    ?>
```

But problem is that when i calling it from live server it is not responding. but it is working fine and giving response in xml format on my local server.

Comment: Check your firewall settings. Production server may have filtering... Check also your SMS provider, their API may also have IP filtering. On your production server, try to call the URL without PHP. On WAMP env use IE or Lynx if you are on LAMP environnement.

Comment: is 'apiurl' the actual URL being used or just a placeholder for the code?

Comment: Also check if the CURL PHP Extension is enabled. Also check `curl_error($ch)`

Comment: Yes @Khôi curl is enabled on both server and it working on my local server. i am facing this problem on live server.

Comment: Have you checked to see what is returned by [curl_error()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)?

Comment: Yes @PatrickQ i checked it returning "couldn't connect to host". what is the reason ?

Comment: You should consider the comments/questions by Kevin and GordonM. Either you're not using the correct URL, or something's blocking the connection.

Comment: @PatrickQ my url is correct I think you are right something's blocking the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install php-curl in your live Server

For Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install php5-curl

```
<?php
        // create curl resource
        $ch = curl_init();

        // set url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

        //return the transfer as a string
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // $output contains the output string
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        // close curl resource to free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);     
?>
```

Comment: i checked using phpinfo(). it is curl is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved. My following code was correct but my web hosting server was blocking
API Port. I told to my hosting provider for unblocking the IP and Port and they did that and now It is working.

```
<?php 
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'apiurl');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch); 
?>
```